# Do we know who is in Cersei's Queensguard?

Tags: game-of-thrones

We obviously know that The Mountain is in the Queensguard but do we know any of the other members in it?

Can we assume that those that were in Joffery's/Tommen's Kingsguard and were still alive at the time Cersei was made queen are in it?

Comment: Do we have any reason to believe that any of them died? I'd assume that if they were dismissed, it was mentioned in the series. I doubt we have another way to know, since the books are not relevant anymore.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam To be honest unless explicitly stated we'd have to assume they are the same as last time it was mentioned as to who they are even if it was only mentioned when they were Robert's/Joffery's/Tommen's guard at the time. Minus any deaths/dismissals of course.